# No Hand Cursor or Mouse Events on Sprites in Flash Player 10

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4.5, flashdevelop

My movie targets flash player 10, and I compile it with FlexSDK v 4.51. It compiles and plays with no errors. 
But if I view the swf in Flash Player 10, some sprites that are set to buttonmode do not show a hand cursor or dispatch MouseEvents.
In fact, if I play it in the Flash Player 10 debug player, I get an error:

```
"VerifyError: Error #1053: Illegal override of z in mx.core.BitmapAsset."
```

So to fix this, I can switch to using an older SDK, version 4.1. Now the error message is gone, but the mouseover problem persists - now for Flash Player version 10 *and* 11.

There are no flash 11 specific features used. It should be targetable using flash player 10. Any ideas how to fix this problem or what is causing it?

==========

## Update

I have determined that the mouse event and the override error are not related. 
The mouse event error seems to being caused by using filters. and I have found a workaround, by applying the filter to a child object, instead of the parent.

The error thrown above, is getting caused by an embedded bitmap. And it seems like a fix to that is to use flex SDK 4.1. Any reason not to just use the 4.1 SDK? Any way to make 4.5 sdk compatible with Flash player 10?

Answer (score 2):

You surely have a class that extends BitmapAsset with a property called `z`. This was not a problem until Flash 10 introduced this as a [built-in member variable](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#z) of any `DisplayObject`.
You should edit this class and change the name of your property.

Comment: Not the case. I tracked it down to the [Embed] tag of a bitmap. And I have no overrides of anything. The illegal override is in the Flex SDK, version 4.5. If I publish with 4.1 - no error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using the latest Flash player? My best guess is you're compiling your program using a Flash version greater than the player is capable of running, e.g. compiling for 11 then running on 10. Have you tried running this in the latest player available?

Answer (score -1):

The error happens because no maybe not any features of 4.5 are use but changed ones are. Simply release with flash player 11 and everything should work fine.

Comment: I don't think changing the spec on a project is an acceptable fix. Thanks. It would reduce the number of users who could view the content without upgrading flash.

Comment: With all the work adobe put into player 11 you should upgrade. Evolution is key here and who doesnt want to download optimization and fixes ?